# Opportunities related list not available under Campaign in scratch orgs

Tags: opportunity, campaign, campaign-influence

I created a new scratch org with the following definition file :

```
{
  "orgName": "Demo company",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": ["EnableSetPasswordInApi"],
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    }
  }
}
```

I want to show the opportunities that are linked to a campaign with the field "Primary Campaign Source", but the related list is not available in the menu under Campaign page layout.
What am I missing ?

I have Marketing User checkbox checked
Default Campaign Influence is enabled

Comment: Can you check [Not able to link opportunities to campaigns](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384494&type=1) ?

Comment: The "Primary Campaign Source" field is visible and I am able to link an opportunity to a campaign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have the Opportunities related list available under Campaign, you need to disable "Campaign Influence"